Ubuntu20.04LTS shows wrong space disk when I installl it
Both Kubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 show wrong space disk when I install them. The free partition is 240GB (figure 1), but the installation process shows 257.7"GB" (figure 2 and figure 3). In Kubuntu 24.04 it shows the size correctly.
The disk is ymtc-pc411, and it has 1024"GB", 953GB. The installation process seems identify  as 1000GB (104+16+214763+257699550679+944 MB=1024205MB=1000.2GB), but I need to use the 20.04 version.
In Windows 10:

Kubuntu 20.04:

Ubuntu 20.04:


It’s just that 1GiB is 0.93GB, so 257.7 GB is almost exactly 240GiB. Windows is showing GiB, Ubuntu and Kubuntu installers are showing as MB - that 257699550679 is 257GB or 240GiB.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (and Kubuntu 20.04 LTS which is now EOL) use the ubiquity installer, where 20.04 LTS uses ubuntu-desktop-installer for Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS and calamares installer for Kubuntu 24.04 LTS; so defaults are just different installer values (see @Will's comment)

Thanks, bro! @Will

Thanks, bro! And is there any way to set the installer to use "MiB" ? @guiverc

Not that I'm aware of, you can select the ISO you download & thus have some choice of installers; 22.04 did earlier on have a canary installer option (that installed is now called ubuntu-desktop-installer) & has calamares, ubiquity and subiquity ISOs, 24.04 has ubuntu-desktop-installer, subiquity & calamares installer ISOs, but each ISO installs different default packages. The installer you use ~once usually, so just accept whatever its default is, is my suggestion...  Anything else will be more work for limited benefit (ie. add other installer etc)

You are right. Thanks, bro!@guiverc
